# Why do Java and C# not have implicit conversions to boolean?

Tags: c#, java, boolean, type-conversion

Since I started Java it's been very aggravating for me that it doesn't support implicit conversions from numeric types to booleans, so you can't do things like:

```
if (flags & 0x80) { ... }
```

instead you have to go through this lunacy:

```
if ((flags & 0x80) != 0) { ... }
```

It's the same with null and objects. Every other C-like language I know including JavaScript allows it, so I thought Java was just moronic, but I've just discovered that C# is the same (at least for numbers, don't know about null/objects):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7(VS.71).aspx

Microsoft changed it on purpose from C++, so why? Clearly I'm missing something. Why change (what I thought was) the most natural thing in the world to make it longer to type? What on Earth is wrong with it?

Comment: It's not lunacy, it's just not what you're used to.

Comment: `if (status = CODE_RED) launch_nuclear_missiles();`

Comment: The real question is, why do languages like C allow the lunacy of implicit conversion to boolean :)

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: In Lisp the empty list is false.  In Python the empty string, dict, tuple, and floating-point zero are also false.  Why doesn't C have these, too?

Comment: Why should an implicit conversion be the default anyway? `flags & 0x80` has nothing to do with the logical concept of `true` and `false`, just because `true` happens to be represented as a non-zero number on *some* systems. It is as wrong as stating that the string `"0"` also should represent `false`. `(flags & 0x80) != 0` on the other hand, now that is a meaningful boolean expression!

Comment: BTW, `/bin/true` returns 0 and `/bin/false` returns 1. Hence for shell scripts `0` is `true` and `non-zero` is `false`.  Why `C` and Java can't follow this simple implicit conversion? :). My brain hurts!!!

Comment: @all implicit conversion haters: i agree with this guy, and it is a valid feature. It is also the default in most if not all dynamic languages. It comes down to the preference of the programmer.

Comment: BTW there is a difference between implicit conversion and error code's. /bin/true returns a error code of non zero on error and zero when the script completed successfully. So I think you've got the two mixed up.

Comment: @PeterLillevold: The expression `someInt & singleBit`, used as indicated, has more to do with truth and falsity than the literal zero has to do with numbers.  What's really needed is to either have an operator which would test whether the bitwise-`and` of two integers was non-zero, or else have the return value of `&` be implicitly convertible to zero even if integers in general were not.

Comment: @supercat - well, as MichaelMyers so nicely put it, do you really want that implicit conversion? Could lead to hell on Earth :) the result of ´someInt & singleBit´ is just a string of bits, which, in the language we're talking about here, can never equal the logical consept of ´true´ and ´false´. You only ever want to compare those strings of bits to other strings of bits. But yes, I agree that it might be better then to improve the language on stuff that we do all the time, though I'm not sure that optimizing ´(flags & 0x80) != 0´ into some special operator is really needed.

Comment: @PeterLillevold: The result of `someInt & singleBit` has only one bit which can be non-zero.  In the case where the mask isn't compile-time recognizable as a single bit, it may make sense to have separate "has any" and "has all" operators.  I dislike the literal zero not from an "optimization" standpoint, but rather the fact that looks like a "value".  Consider the slightly different scenario: `(Thing1.Flags & THING1_FLAG_WHATEVER) == (Things2.Flags & THING2_FLAG_WHATEVER)`, with the intention of testing whether the two things are in agreement. The code will work if the masks are the same...

Comment: ...but changing the things to use different masks will break it.  If there were a `.&.` operator, `(Thing1.Flags .&. THING1_FLAG_WHATEVER) == (Things2.Flags .&. THING2_FLAG_WHATEVER)` would be cleaner than `((Thing1.Flags & THING1_FLAG_WHATEVER) != 0) == ((Things2.Flags & THING2_FLAG_WHATEVER) != 0)`.

Answer (score 37):

For clarity. It makes the following mistake simply illegal:

```
int x = ...;

if (x = 0)  // in C: assign 0 to x and always evaluate to false 
   ....     // never executed
```

Note: most modern C / C++ compilers will give a Warning (but not an Error) on this straightforward pattern, but there are many variations possible. It can creep up on you.

Comment: In theory, in C# it's possible that the type of `x` implements implicit conversion operators from `int` and to `bool`, in which case this would compile in C#. If you qualify that `x` is a built in numeric type (like `int`), then your example is absolutely correct.

Comment: @LBushkin, you're right, I'll add it. But assuming  a custom conversion is a little far fetched here.

Comment: Many of the Underhanded C submissions feature this little chestnut tucked away somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 33):

Both Java and C# abandoned implicit conversions to booleans **to reduce the chance of programmer error**.

For example, many programmers would accidentally write:

```
if( x = 5 ) { ... }
```

instead of:

```
if( x == 5 ) { ... }
```

Which of course results in completely different behavior, since the first statement performs an assignment (which will always result in true), while the second performs a comparison. In the past, developers would sometimes write such assignments in reverse to avoid the pitfall, since:

```
if( 5 = x ) { ... } // doesn't compile.
```

Now, in C#, you can still create implicit conversion operators to `bool` for your own types - although it is rarely advisable, since most developers don't expect it:

```
public class MyValue
{
   public int Value { get; set; }

   public static implicit operator bool( MyValue mb )
   {
       return mb.Value != 0;
   }
}

MyValue x = new MyValue() { Value = 10; }
if( x ) { ... } // perfectly legal, compiler applies implicit conversion
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe they felt that being more explicit was more in line with a strongly typed language.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer

Answer (score 9):

You've got it backward.
It's actually C that does not support `boolean`, so `if` ( and any other conditional statement ) actually expects an `int` value, not `boolean`.  Then int value of `0` is treated as false and any other value is treated as `true`.

Some people actually find it a little ambiguous, because this type of behavior can lead to many errors, as others have pointed out.  Because of this, Java designers have opted out to support only `boolean` types in the condition statements.  And when Microsoft decided to implement MS-Java ( AKA C# ), they've borrowed this design principal.

If you don't like it, you can program in a variety of languages that do not have this restriction.

Answer (score 7):

Implicit conversion of any int value (such as (flags & 0x80)) to a boolean implies a language defined mapping from an int value to a boolean. C did this, and caused a huge amount of confusion and a lot of programmer error. There is no good reason why a zero int value ALWAYS means true (or false) and a lot of good reasons why you might want to leave the decision to the programmer. For these reasons implicit conversion to boolean has been abandoned by most modern languages.

If typing seven extra characters every time you do a bit test constitutes 'lunacy' you may be in the wrong profession. If you are doing bit tests in an int extremely frequently you might want to think about whether you are prematurely optimizing to save memory.

Comment: Such "lunacy" is why we have the `++` operator, which used to optimize to INCR instructions but now just serve as a typing shortcut.

Comment: I agree. Implicit conversions to booleans can be useful, but declaring that some arbitrary values are false and some other equally arbitrary values are true is not the way. In Ruby and many Lisps for example, *everything* is true, except for `false` and `nil`. That's a *simple* and obvious rule. "Some numbers are true and some are false, unless you write your own number type in which case they are neither true nor false" is not exactly a simple rule. Also, why should numbers be true or false but not, say, matrices? Or `User` s?

Answer (score 3):

Even the most experienced programmers have problems with an implicit conversion to boolean. I for one appreciate this little feature.

Answer (score 2):

Some programming languages do no automatic coercion at all. An integer, for example, can only be compared to another integer; assignment to a non-integer variable results in an error. Such is the hallmark of a strongly-typed language.

That Java does any coercion is a convenience for you and breaks the strong-typing model.

Mapping the entire range of integers -- or the even larger range of floats -- onto the two boolean values is fraught with disagreement over arbitrary assignment of "truthness" and "falseness".

- What values map onto false and true? If you're C, only zero maps to false and all other values are true. If you're the bash shell, it's reversed.
- How should negative values be mapped?

When you try to automatically convert a double to an integer, Java flags this as a "loss of precision" error. By analogy, converting a number to a boolean should also result in a loss of precision. Instead, Java chose to not syntactically support it.

Comment: I know of no debate of how to map `int` to `bool`. Could you provide a link?

Comment: There's no official debate, per se. But since some languages have different ideas of how to do the conversion, there's clearly no standard.

Comment: Well there is a standard its X86 and the ALU. True is evaluated to be none zero, and false zero. Simple ALU 'and' instruction set. There is no standard per say because its critical how modern day computers work.