# Why is Char implicitly converted to a Int?

Tags: java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In Java, why is a char primitive implicitly converted to an int primitive? People say it's because of a widening conversion - that a 2-byte char will fit in an 4-byte int, but what about booleans? Booleans certainly take up less than 2 bytes, yet they are not implicitly converted.

Comment: Java was designed in a way that only `true` or `false` were valid conditions. For example, you can't do `while(1)` like in other languages. So it doesn't make sense to consider booleans as integers.

Comment: In what context you are talking about? Conversion happens differently in different context.

Comment: Conversion like this: char test = 'a'; int test2 = test;

Comment: There is no good answer to the "why" chars are silently converted to ints here. It was really just a bad design choice and now they're stuck with it. There are many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java developers didn't want Boolean to convert into any int type implicitly, as it was ambiguous in C language. Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951757/why-do-java-and-c-sharp-not-have-implicit-conversions-to-boolean)

Comment: Actually there is nothing "ambiguous" about the conversion.  The problem is that the conversion legal makes a common programming mistake dangerous by making it valid code.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean is not a numerical datatype, so an implicity conversion is not defined.

But fortunately it is easy to convert a boolean to any int you'd like:

```
int value = b ? 1 : 2; // if b is true, value will be 1, else 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

A conversion from char to int is needed because no operators are defined for chars: you can't check if a char is greater than another or if a char is in a given range without converting to int first.

The same is true for booleans on the JVM level, the difference is that you don't need to do these operations on them (true > false seems a little arbitrary) while operations on chars are needed to implement things like character encoding conversion and case conversion.