# Why can't I use an integer as a condition for a while loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop, boolean, conditional-statements

I am getting an error when using the while loop shown below, and I don't understand why:

```
int count = 5;
while(count--)    //here showing an error
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}", count);
}
```

However, in C, the code works properly. I am a little bit confused about why I am getting this error. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks, for your invaluable time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get a good experience using this site, please have a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951757/why-do-java-and-c-sharp-not-have-implicit-conversions-to-boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not define an implicit conversion from `int` to `bool`. The `while` loop condition must be a `bool`.

You should use `while(count-- != 0)` instead.

In `C#` you have a `bool` type which accepts `True` or `False` as value. In `C` everything other than `0` is true and `0` indicates null. So you can have `if (1)` in `C` but `1` is not a logical expression in `C#`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.your suggestion is great.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not allow implicit casts from `int` to `bool(ean)`. You should explicitly do that:

```
int count = 5;
while(count-- != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While loop is using `bool` values to determine if continue loop or exit loop

In Your example `count` value is `int` and this cause error/

Simple refactorig is this:

```
            int count = 5;

            while (count != 0 )
            {
                count--;
                Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}", count);
            }
```

Now when count value will by 0 it will break loop

Comment: It should probably be `count != 0`.

Comment: Thanks.Now it's clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it!

```
while (count-- >= 0)//here showing an error
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}", count);
            }
```

Comment: This will work, but it will be *different* behavior from C, where a count of 0 terminates the loop. I only point that out because the asker specifically mentions the C behavior in the question. Aside from that, you could make this answer *much* better if you included some explanation of *why* this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks brother.I am trying to learn c# and it's my first question in this site.